# Virtual Attribute is nil when saving via accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I save a record through nested attributes, the virtual attribute doesn't get set in the child model.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :houses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :houses
end

class House < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :house_name  #virtual
  before_save do 
    puts attributes # doesn't include house_name when saving through parent model
    puts @house_name # nil when saving through parent model
  end

end

person = Person.find(1)
person.houses.count #=> 3
person.houses.first.house_name = 'crazy house'
person.save # house_name not in attributes

house = person.houses.first
house.house_name = 'moms house'
house.save #house_name is in attributes
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
person.houses.first.house_name = 'crazy house'
```

fetches the first associated `House`. `Person` has no way to know if you change it's house. You just overestimated the magic, I guess. All you need is to `update_attributes` of the house:

```
person.houses.first.update_attributes house_name: 'crazy house'
```

Comment: that does make sense.  Would it be the same if saving a params hash?  ie - @person.update_attributes(params[:person])

Comment: `house_name: 'crazy house'` is a `Hash` so you are free to supply your own instead.

Comment: right but thats a hash updating just the house, not through the parent object which is what I would like ideally..

Comment: `House` should be updated via nested attributes. I dare to assume that something wrong with `params[:person]`. Maybe it's a result of improperly generated form that fills this params?